# Find my phone stopped working from homepod

Tags: siri, find-my-iphone, homepod

I use find my phone often by asking siri on my homepod.

However without changing anything siri now says "before I can help with that you'll  need to update your information in siri settings on  your iphone "

Now there is no siri settings on the phone  there  is in settings a section for siri and search. Which exact settings do I need to change?

I found my phone by logging into icloud on my desktop and running find my from there. My phone made a sound with no problem. Using find my from my ipad made the phone make a sound as well

So what does the homepod need and will that change how my desktop or ipad finds the phone?
All running ios 14

Comment: On your iPhone in `Settings -> Siri & Search`, I'm assuming your "My Information" is all still correct?

Comment: Yes unchanged and enough for others

Comment: You've done the usual restart dance, correct?  Also, are all devices on the same wifi network?  I'm grasping at straws here, if you can't tell.

Comment: Yes and yes although the network better not matter if the phone is eksewhere

Comment: And today it just works again

Comment: See?  It just works!

Comment: I'm having the same problem and apparently there're just two of us in the entire Internet

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem when trying to launch a third party app via Homepod, either directly or in a Shortcut. Turns out you have to give explicit permission for Siri to use it with a particular app. Go to `Settings -> Siri & Search` on your iPhone, scroll down to the list of apps, open the app you wish to use with Siri, scroll down and turn on `"Use with Ask Siri"`. If you hear Siri saying this when trying to use Apple own apps like Find My, the only thing I can think about is enabling Personal Requests, as described here https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/homepod/apd779d9bb45/1.0/homepod/1.0#apdf41297105

Comment: True but not relevant. The apps and settings I had were the same before and after the problem happened

Comment: Sorry! I tried my best :) Homepod is full of problems and inconsistencies sadly, didn't expect that from an Apple product